# How to Replace Variable with Level in tbl_summary

Tags: gtsummary

A reviewer asked that rather than have both genders listed in the table, to just include one. So, Gender would be replaced with Female and the proportions of the gender that was female would be under each Treatment.

```
library(gtsummary)
d<-tibble::tribble(
      ~Gender, ~Treatment,      
      "Male", "A",
      "Male", "B", 
      "Female", "A",
      "Male", "C",
      "Female", "B",
      "Female", "C")

d %>% tbl_summary(by = Treatment)
```

Comment: `d %>% dplyr::filter(Gender == "Female") %>% tbl_summary(by = Treatment)` , you can just subset to a specific gender first and then run the table

Comment: Almost, they want it to look like this
[link]https://imgur.com/NS2r2F6

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to remove the first row of `table_body` and only keep the second row of `table_body` this will only keep the information on `Female`. This matches your table you provided in the comments.

```
library(gtsummary)
d<-tibble::tribble(
  ~Gender, ~Treatment,      
  "Male", "A",
  "Male", "B", 
  "Female", "A",
  "Male", "C",
  "Female", "B",
  "Female", "C")

t1 <- d %>% filter(Gender == "Female") %>% tbl_summary(by = Treatment)



t1$table_body <- t1$table_body[2,]

t1
```

[image]

Comment: This almost works but because it is filtered for only Female, the total N on top of each column is off. The N for each column should be two, not one.